# 2次元配列で値の代入と表示を別のfor文で書く方法を教えていただきたいです

Tags: java

現在２次元配列を勉強しており、問題の中で「doubleの配列を作成し、要素[x][y]の値をx*yにしましょう(初期化子を使わず)。」というものがありました。
そこで一つのfor文にまとめて表示はできたのですが、次に別々のfor文に代入と表示をしましょうというものがありました。
そこが考えていたのですがどうやってもうまく表示ができません。

以下コードから表示と代入を別のfor文に書き換えるにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか。

```
double [][] s = new double[7][6];
    for (int x = 1; x < s.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 1; y < s[x].length; y++) {
            s[x][y] = x * y;
            System.out.println(s[x][y]);

        }
    }
```

教えていただければ幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

単純に別のfor文に分けたいだけならば、下記のようにすれば良い気がしました。

```
for (int x = 1; x < s.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < s[x].length; y++) {
        s[x][y] = x * y;
    }
}
for (int x = 1; x < s.length; x++) {
     for (int y = 1; y < s[x].length; y++) {
         System.out.println(s[x][y]);
     }
}
```

下記のようにするともうすこしデータが見やすくなるかもしれません。

```
// ファイルの先頭でjava.utils.Arraysをimport
import java.util.Arrays;

for (int x = 1; x < s.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 1; y < s[x].length; y++) {
        s[x][y] = x * y;
    }
}
for (double [] data: s) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
}
```

Comment: 下の方法はかなり見やすいですね！そういったやり方もあるのですね。。勉強になりました！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

質問の意味がよく分からないですが、つまりこういうことでしょうか？
代入(`s = x * y`)と表示(`System.out.println(s[x][y])`)を別々のfor文で。

```
double[][] s = new double[7][6];

for (int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < s[x].length; y++) {
        s = x * y;
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < s[x].length; y++) {
        System.out.println(s[x][y]);
    }
}
```

Comment: そうすれば2つにすることができるのですね。。すみません、ありがとうございました！！

Answer (score 0):

直接本題には関係しませんのでコメントで残そうと思いましたが、評価が足りなかったのでこちらに書かせていただきます。

おそらくですが配列の添え字が１から始まるのではなく、０から始まるかなと思われます。
litmon様が書いているようにfor文で使用するカウンターの変数のスタートが０であると思われます。

もちろん言語によって添え字１から始まる仕様のものがあるかもしれません。
その場合には、for文の終了条件部分が n < lengthではなく、n <= lengthになるかなと思います。

配列の中がどうなっているか、出力関数に最大値の添え字を配列に指定した場合、０を指定した場合１を指定した場合などご確認いただくことを推奨します。

おそらくですが、現在の状態ですと配列の0番地（1個目相当）が未初期化状態になっているかなと思います。